If two persons split the minting process payment 80-20% on opensea , what are the rights and risks of each one on NFT?
I am new to NFT minting.
I created a collection and am about to create a NFT .
Someone has a buying customer on opensea for my Artwork to be minted. He suggests to pay 20% of the minting fees while I pay 80% on opensea minting process so he gets a profit from the eventual NFT sale.
Is this possible to share the minting payment this way  on opensea ?
Do I put to risk any confidential  information on my wallet by doing so ?
What are the risks for me ?
Who owns The minted NFT ?
Who can fix the NFT price ?
Who can sell the NFT ?
Who will get the ETH amount from the sale?
Is this possibly a scam ?
Thanks
